How to add "Add to Cart" button on live search listing page in Adobe commerce Cloud
Any idea how we can add the "add to cart" and wishlist button on the live search listing page? I am using Live search in Adobe commerce, Cloud version 2.4.6 version.
On Default live search listing page only image, name, price is coming.


Did you find any solution for this? I want to add swatches on Live search results.

I've find the way to add the Add to cart button on product recommendation
app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_ProductRecommendationsLayout/web/template/recommendations.html
Same way can add other functionality like Add to wishlist, compare
For Listing page you've to develop functionality in react
component first
https://github.com/adobe/storefront-product-listing-page
                                        <div class="button-section">
                                            <div class="product-item-inner" data-bind="if: $data.productId && $data.addToCartAllowed">
                                                <div class="product-item-actions">
                                                    <div class="actions-primary">
                                                        <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                                            attr="action: addToCart.url"
                                                            data-bind="mageInit: {'catalogAddToCart': {'bindSubmit': true,'product_sku': sku}}"
                                                            method="post">
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="product" attr="value: productId"/>
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="uenc" attr="value: addToCart.postUenc" />
                                                            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" attr="value: addToCart.form_key" />
                                                            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary"
                                                                    data-bind="attr : {'data-sku' : sku, 'data-unit-id': $parent.unitId }">
                                                                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Add to Cart'"></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                            <a href="#" title="Add to WishList" class="action towishlist"
                                                                    data-bind="click: $parents[1].addToWishList.bind($data),  attr : {'data-sku' : sku, 'data-unit-id': $parent.unitId }"
                                                                    data-action="add-to-wishlist">
                                                                <span data-bind="i18n: 'WishList'"></span>
                                                            </a>
                                                            <a title="Add to Compare" class="action tocompare"
                                                                    data-bind="click: $parents[1].addToCompare.bind($data),  attr : {'data-sku' : sku, 'data-unit-id': $parent.unitId }"  >
                                                                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Add to Compare'"></span>
                                                            </a>
                                                        
                                                        </form>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


*app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
<!-- Loop through search results -->

<div class="product-item">
    <h2><?php echo $product->getName(); ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $product->getPrice(); ?></p>
    <!-- Add to Cart button -->
    <form data-role="tocart-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $product->getId(); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey(); ?>">
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
            <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>


I'm using the Live Search feature of Adobe Commerce Enterprise Cloud version. Not the default one.

If you're using Adobe Commerce Cloud with the Live Search feature, the process might be a bit different because Live Search could involve some dynamic rendering of search results, potentially using JavaScript and AJAX.
To add an "Add to Cart" button in the Live Search results, you'll typically need to modify the JavaScript code that handles the rendering of search results and the interaction with the Add to Cart functionality.
